# numpy genetic algorithm selection: roulette wheel vs. stochastic universal sampling

Tags: python, numpy, genetic-algorithm

I am implementing a genetic algorithm in numpy and I'm trying to figure out how to correctly implement selection via roulette wheel and stochastic universal sampling. The examples I've seen on stackoverflow or elsewhere use a python loop rather than vectorized numpy code.

For example, here are the implementations of both algorithms in DEAP.

```
def selRoulette(individuals, k, fit_attr="fitness"):
    """Select *k* individuals from the input *individuals* using *k*
    spins of a roulette. The selection is made by looking only at the first
    objective of each individual. The list returned contains references to
    the input *individuals*.
    :param individuals: A list of individuals to select from.
    :param k: The number of individuals to select.
    :param fit_attr: The attribute of individuals to use as selection criterion
    :returns: A list of selected individuals.
    This function uses the :func:`~random.random` function from the python base
    """
    s_inds = sorted(individuals, key=attrgetter(fit_attr), reverse=True)
    sum_fits = sum(getattr(ind, fit_attr).values[0] for ind in individuals)
    chosen = []
    for i in xrange(k):
        u = random.random() * sum_fits
        sum_ = 0
        for ind in s_inds:
            sum_ += getattr(ind, fit_attr).values[0]
            if sum_ > u:
                chosen.append(ind)
                break

    return chosen

def selStochasticUniversalSampling(individuals, k, fit_attr="fitness"):
    """Select the *k* individuals among the input *individuals*.
    The selection is made by using a single random value to sample all of the
    individuals by choosing them at evenly spaced intervals. The list returned
    contains references to the input *individuals*.
    :param individuals: A list of individuals to select from.
    :param k: The number of individuals to select.
    :param fit_attr: The attribute of individuals to use as selection criterion
    :return: A list of selected individuals.
    """
    s_inds = sorted(individuals, key=attrgetter(fit_attr), reverse=True)
    sum_fits = sum(getattr(ind, fit_attr).values[0] for ind in individuals)

    distance = sum_fits / float(k)
    start = random.uniform(0, distance)
    points = [start + i*distance for i in xrange(k)]

    chosen = []
    for p in points:
        i = 0
        sum_ = getattr(s_inds[i], fit_attr).values[0]
        while sum_ < p:
            i += 1
            sum_ += getattr(s_inds[i], fit_attr).values[0]
        chosen.append(s_inds[i])

    return chosen
```

Here is my implementation of roulette wheel, which seems to be weighted sampling with replacement, but I'm not sure about the replacement parameter.

```
# population is a 2D array of integers
# population_fitness is a 1D array of float of same length as population

weights = population_fitness / population_fitness.sum()
selected = population[np.random.choice(len(population), size=n, replace=True, p=weights)]
```

And here is my implementation of SUS selection. Am I correct that, when implemented in numpy, the only thing I have to change is that sampling is without replacement, or should I also remove the weights?

```
weights = population_fitness / population_fitness.sum()
selected = population[np.random.choice(len(population), size=n, replace=False, p=weights)]
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both strategies can possibly select the same individual multiple times, so replacement is not the point.

I don't know how `np.random.choice` is implemented internally, but anyway the implementation method is not specified in the contract of the function (and so it could change at any time). Below I give my implementation of both selection strategies using numpy.
**Please, make sure to test these functions before using them in anything serious.**

**EDIT:** sorting by fitness was not necessary; I don't know what I had in mind.

```py
import numpy as np

formatters = {
    'int': lambda x: '%4d' % x,
    'float': lambda x: '%.02f' % x
}

def print_report(population, fitness, wheel, selectors, selected_individuals):
    with np.printoptions(formatter=formatters):
        print('          Population:', population)
        print('             Fitness:', fitness)
        print('      Roulette wheel:', wheel)       # fitness cumulative sum
        print('      Sampled values:', selectors)   # roulette "extractions"
        print('Selected individuals:', selected_individuals)


# This should be equivalent to np.choice(population, size, weights=fitness)
def roulette_wheel_selection(rng: np.random.Generator,
                             population: np.ndarray,
                             fitness: np.ndarray,
                             size: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """ :Authors: Gianluca Gippetto """
    if size > len(population):
        raise ValueError
    fitness_cumsum = fitness.cumsum()   # the "roulette wheel"
    fitness_sum = fitness_cumsum[-1]    # sum of all fitness values (size of the wheel)
    sampled_values = rng.random(size) * fitness_sum
    # For each sampled value, get the corresponding roulette wheel slot
    selected = np.searchsorted(fitness_cumsum, sampled_values)
    print_report(population, fitness, fitness_cumsum, sampled_values, selected)
    return selected


def sus(rng: np.random.Generator,
        population: np.ndarray,
        fitness: np.ndarray,
        size: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_universal_sampling
    :Authors: Gianluca Gippetto """
    if size > len(population):
        raise ValueError

    fitness_cumsum = fitness.cumsum()
    fitness_sum = fitness_cumsum[-1]  # the "roulette wheel"
    step = fitness_sum / size         # we'll move by this amount in the wheel
    start = rng.random() * step       # sample a start point in [0, step)
    # get N evenly-spaced points in the wheel
    selectors = np.arange(start, fitness_sum, step)
    selected = np.searchsorted(fitness_cumsum, selectors)
    print_report(population, fitness, fitness_cumsum, selectors, selected)
    return selected


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy.random import default_rng

    n = 10
    sample_size = 5
    rng = default_rng()
    # Random population data.
    # I'm sorting by fitness just for making it easier to read the report
    population = np.arange(n)
    fitness = np.sort(
        np.abs(rng.normal(size=len(population)))
    )

    print('Roulette wheel sampling:')
    roulette_wheel_selection(rng, population, fitness, sample_size)
    print()

    print('SUS:')
    sus(rng, population, fitness, sample_size)
```

Output:

```
Roulette wheel sampling:
          Population: [   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9]
             Fitness: [0.34 0.35 0.47 0.61 0.62 0.67 0.73 0.84 1.12 1.93]
      Roulette wheel: [0.34 0.69 1.16 1.77 2.39 3.06 3.79 4.64 5.75 7.69]
      Sampled values: [0.93 3.93 5.32 7.10 4.11]
Selected individuals: [   2    7    8    9    7]

SUS:
          Population: [   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9]
             Fitness: [0.34 0.35 0.47 0.61 0.62 0.67 0.73 0.84 1.12 1.93]
      Roulette wheel: [0.34 0.69 1.16 1.77 2.39 3.06 3.79 4.64 5.75 7.69]
      Sampled values: [1.25 2.79 4.33 5.86 7.40]
Selected individuals: [   3    5    7    9    9]
```